# Firestore - How to get the doc id from FirebaseFirestore.QuerySnapshot?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm querying a collection for a specific document and trying to get the document-ID from the result of my query that is from type FirebaseFirestore.QuerySnapshot.

My actual query looks like this (I'm using async/await):

```
result = await db.collection("chatrooms").where("userA", "==", req.body.userA)
            .where("userB", "==", req.body.userB).limit(1).get();
```

I tried with:

```
await result.docs.map(doc => {
            return doc.id
        })
```

But that gives me an `undefined` back.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A QuerySnapshot contains zero or more DocumentSnapshot objects representing the results of a query. The documents can be accessed as an array via the docs property or enumerated using the forEach method. The number of documents can be determined via the empty and size properties.

So it's going to return an array (QuerySnapshot) of `QueryDocumentSnapshot`s. You need to loop over the snapshots using [forEach()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html#foreach) then you can get the document ID from each `QueryDocumentSnapshot`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot

If you're using typescript, you should be able to see the definitions, methods, and properties in your IDE.

Comment: in VSCode, even if writing in JS you still can see the TS definitions if you hover over Firebase code.

Comment: I used forEach() on my code but still got undefined. how can i get the value return from async and use it on another function that need to be run after the async?

Comment: The link is broken, could you update with newer link?